# grails params with #

Tags: grails, parameters

Anyone know how to either get Grails to accept parameters preceded with a #

Example: http://ax:8080/oidc/landing#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6

I could either get the full URL, which isn't entirely clear how to obtain that with the arguments

Or configure Grails to accept the # if that is possible.

I searched and can't find an obvious solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: you can't. # is an HTML anchor and can be accessed only in js context.

Comment: Essentially the # (and anything after it), are never sent to the server at all.